# What is the correct way of closing a homework question?

Tags: discussion, flags

While reviewing questions, I often come across questions that are clearly homework questions, and even comments say so, however when I try to flag it, I'm never sure what reason to give.

I've used too broad, because sometimes the question kind of asks for a solution to the whole problem, and sometimes I've used the "not sure what is being asked" option.

What is the correct way to handle these types of questions? shouldn't there be an off-topic sub-category for them?

Comment: Your question pre-supposes that homework questions are off topic. And I have never seen it said that that is the case.

Comment: @mason - Nowhere in the site's documentation but many people will tell OPs not to post HW questions. I actually thought there was a rule against it at one point because I'd seen so many people complaining about it.

Comment: @BSMP Then those people are wrong, and should be corrected so that they discontinue spreading misinformation.

Comment: Just.. Forget about homework. Entirely disregard it. Pretend it isn't homework. Then look at the question again.

Comment: As long as the question is well written I don't understand why a student programmer running into a problem and asking for help is different from a professional or hobbyist programmer running into a problem and asking for help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It *really doesn't matter* if the question is homework-motivated.  If it's off-topic in some way, shape or form, then close it with one of the reasons provided, or a custom close reason if none are suitable (which is rarer nowadays).

The whole idea behind homework questions being bad isn't entirely true, and while there are quite a number of them which are terrible, there are a number of them that are very good and should be kept open.

If you do run into a question that's off-topic, flag/vote to close accordingly.  But don't vote on it just because it's a homework question.

Comment: Oh well, maybe I did not explain myself very well. I meant those hw questions that are blatantly trying to just get *the* answer without regard for understanding why, or actually learning. Kind of like copy-pasting the hw question verbatim and then expecting actual running code as an answer.

Comment: Then close them as too broad.  We get tons of questions that *aren't* related to homework that read the same way.  They get no special treatment, and neither should homework questions that appear the same.

Comment: What about the part where it is a homework question, but it doesn't "include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."? That's listed as one of the "off-topic" reasons, but's its not a choice in the "Flagging >> Closing >> Off-Topic".

Comment: @PeterHaight:  Treat it like you would any other question that doesn't include a summary of the work done, or doesn't include the description necessary.  The fact that the question is homework-based is ***irrelevant.***

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. That clears it up for me. Maybe it should be removed from the list of "off-topic even if it fits into one of the categories" section on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. That sentence really implies that a homework question "without a summary of the work done ..." is "off-topic", but everyone here is saying it's not off-topic, but instead it's badly written.